# No results message on jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling no results in jquery autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849415/handling-no-results-in-jquery-autocomplete)

I'd like to give a "No matches" message on a [jquery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) when the result is empty.

A partial answer was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849415/handling-no-results-in-jquery-autocomplete), but it doesn't explain exactly how to show the "No matches" result in the autocomplete dropdown.

UPDATE: Here is my code based on the current answers..

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="myAutocomplete" id="myAutocomplete">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#myAutocomplete").autocomplete("ajax.php", {
    selectFirst: false,
    resultsClass: 'my_results_class',
    parse: function(data) {
        if (!data || data.length == 0) {
            $('#myAutocomplete option').val('No Matches');
        }
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        if($(ui.item).val() == 'No Matches')
            $(ui.item).disable();
    },
    select: function(event, ui){
        if($(ui.item).val() == 'No Matches')
            return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, return a result with the value 'No matches' or whatever you want,then on the jquery autocompleter add these handlers

```
focus: function(event, ui){ 
    if($(ui.item).val() == 'No Matches')
        $(ui.item).disable();
},
select: function(event, ui){
    if($(ui.item).val() == 'No Matches')
        return false;
},
```

This should prevent the user from selecting the entry 'No Matches'.

Comment: Aldo, is this correct?

http://pastebin.com/VUcW8MRg

It's not showing the "No matches" text

Comment: Check if your autocomplete has an id of 'dropdown_id', if it doesn't either give it that id, or change it in the code

Comment: Oh, i see.. you're referencing the other answer.. The id is indeed matching

Comment: The snippet you posted kind of mixed the two answers, that's why I said so

Comment: I updated the question to include my current HTML + jQuery.. What change should I make?

Comment: I don't know why you're messing with it so much. Remove the `parse:` from the autocomplete options, and on ajax.php check if there are no results add one, with the label 'No Matches' And it'll work like a charm.

Comment: Aldo, good advice.. I'm going to do that.. at this point I'm just curious as to how I would do it with parse though

Comment: Aldo, the focus and select aren't being set off. I put alerts inside them to verify this.  Basically, neither is preventing 'No Matches' from going into the text input.  Writing these events out in the form $("#myAutoComplete").focus... makes focus set off, when you click in the text, but aside from that neither event is set off and it's still not working at stopping 'No Matches' from going in

Comment: Here's my implementation (http://pastebin.com/sEwxweCb).

In that code I disallow selecting a hr tag which is on the suggestion list. just replace <hr> with 'No Matches' and it should work

Comment: Aldo, it's not even calling the focus or select events when they use it..  I put alerts there and they never go off

Comment: Now I feel terribly ashamed! I didnt even check the link you provided I just assumed it as jquery UI Autocomplete. The above example works only for that library. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849415/handling-no-results-in-jquery-autocomplete), you need to add this code between:

```
 if (!data || data.length == 0) {
         // handle no data case specially
 }
```

Making it:

```
 if (!data || data.length == 0) {
   $('#dropdown_id option').val('No Matches');
 }
```

**Update:**

Instead of:

```
$('#myAutocomplete option').val('No Matches');
```

Use:

```
$('#myAutocomplete').val('No Matches');
```

**Update:**

Use:

```
$('#school-term').val('No Matches');
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not getting the "No matches" text with this code: http://pastebin.com/VUcW8MRg

Comment: Make sure that you specify the id to dropdown and specify that correctly in the code, also try this variation: `$('#dropdown_id').val('No Matches');`

Comment: the id is correctly specified.  When I do $('#dropdown_id').val('No Matches'); it puts it directly in the input rather than in the dropdown.  Are you sure "option" is the right thing?  Maybe im wrong but I thought the autocomplete works through a list rather than an option select..?

Comment: @babonk: Make sure that you have specified the same id to more than one elment for example text field and dropdown. `dropdown_id` should be the id of dropdown eg `<select id="dropdown_id">`

Comment: I updated the question to include my current HTML + jQuery.. What change should I make?

Comment: @babonk: see my update please. Your dropdown keyword you said created the confusion

Comment: $('#myAutocomplete').val('No Matches'); makes it show "No Matches" in the text input

Comment: @babonk: That is what you updated in your question, should it show elsewhere?

Comment: It should show in the autocomplete dropdown, same as results do

Comment: @babonk: Please post the html for your dropdown too in your question.

Comment: There is no html for the dropdown.. it's all handled by the autocomplete jQuery

Comment: @babonk: Show me the link of your page i will check out myself

Comment: @babonk: see my update 2 please

Comment: @sarfaz: by first dropdown, i mean first autocomplete (Your School).  And like I said, doing $('#school-name').val('No Matches'); makes it show "No Matches" in the text input, not in the dropdown of it

Comment: o man i said `$('#school-term').val('No Matches');` not `$('#school-name').val('No Matches');` Can't you see the difference of ids in both lines?

Comment: Yes, I see the difference, thats why I clarified above..  Term is not related to this..  I want the drop down on school-name to change