# Problems with jQuery autocomplete + AngularJS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-autocomplete

i'm using AjgularJS on my page and want to add a field to use autocomplete from jqueryui and the autocomplete does not fires the ajax call.

i've tested the script on a page without angular (ng-app and ng-controller) and it works well, but when i put the script on a page with angularjs it stops working.

any idea?

jquery script:

```
$(function () {

    $('#txtProduct').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {

            alert(request.term);

        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {

        }
    });

});
```

- interesting note: when i call the script on Chrome inspector the autocomplete starts working!!!
- Versions: AngularJS: 1.0.2 - JqueryUI: 1.9.0

**CONCLUSION:**
The autocomplete widget from jQueryUI must be initializes from inside a custom directive of AngularJS as the example:

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <h2>index</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">

        <input type="text" auto-complete>ddd</input>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

    function TestCtrl($scope) { }

    app.directive('autoComplete', function () {
        return function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

            $(function () {
                $(iElement).autocomplete({
                    source: function (req, resp) {
                        alert(req.term);
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You should try loading them in $(document).ready(); Also check for errors in firebug console.

Comment: Agreed - you will need to check for conflicts between AngularJS and JQuery. There don't appear to be any in a simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/w69Wt/

Comment: It may not be relevant from the problem you are seeing, but I think you should be use jquery inside the custom directive (link function).

Comment: Thanks guys, the solution that work for me is the suggested by tosh, creating a custom directive for that!!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Perhaps you just need to do it in an "angular way"... that is, to use a directive to set up your DOM elements and do event bindings, use a service to get your data, and use a controller to do your business logic... all while leveraging the dependency injection goodness that is Angular...

A service to get your autocomplete data...

```
app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function() {
    return {
        getSource: function() {
            //this is where you'd set up your source... could be an external source, I suppose. 'something.php'
            return ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
        }
    }
}]);
```

a directive to do the work of setting up the autocomplete plugin.

```
app.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                    // elem is a jquery lite object if jquery is not present,
                    // but with jquery and jquery ui, it will be a full jquery object.
            elem.autocomplete({
                source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), //from your service
                minLength: 2
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And using it in your markup... notice the ng-model to set a value on the $scope with what you select.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo" auto-complete/>
    Foo = {{foo}}
</div>
```

That's just the basics, but hopefully that helps.

Comment: The elem.autocomplete needs to be $(elem).autocomplete

Comment: @AshMcConnell: if jQuery is registered on the page before Angular, the elem argument to the link function is a jQuery object already. So no $() required. ;) Angular is slick like that.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know that, I'll check the import order when I get back to work tomorrow! (It's just the order of imports you mean?)

Comment: Correct, as long as your `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` is before your `<script src="angular.js"></script>`, it should use jQuery objects rather than jqLite objects for Elements within Angular.

Comment: How to put `<input type="text" ng-model="foo" auto-complete/>` in Jade Template? It sets `auto-complete="auto-complete"`

Comment: I've found that I need to update ngModel on the "select" event

Answer (score 14):

I had to do a bit more work to get this working using an $http service.

The service:

```
app.factory("AutoCompleteService", ["$http", function ($http) {
    return {
        search: function (term) {
            return $http.get("http://YourServiceUrl.com/" + term).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The directive:

```
app.directive("autocomplete", ["AutoCompleteService", function (AutoCompleteService) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            elem.autocomplete({
                source: function (searchTerm, response) {
                    AutoCompleteService.search(searchTerm.term).then(function (autocompleteResults) {
                        response($.map(autocompleteResults, function (autocompleteResult) {
                            return {
                                label: autocompleteResult.YourDisplayProperty,
                                value: autocompleteResult 
                            }
                        }))
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, selectedItem) {
                    // Do something with the selected item, e.g. 
                    scope.yourObject= selectedItem.item.value;
                    scope.$apply();
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The html:

```
<input ng-model="YourObject" autocomplete />
```

Comment: I am getting  following  error 'Error: autocompleteResult is not defined'

Comment: Is your service returning any information? For example, in my service I'm returning response.data. If you are also returning that, make sure your service call is also returning data.

Comment: @Jason: can u please show me the format for json return data from get method.

Comment: @Siddesh Bhalke: Any arbitrary json can be returned by your service. In this example, autocompleteResults is an array of objects each of which has a property named 'YourDisplayProperty'.

Comment: I had a problem that the list was disappearing before anyone could click anything. I fixed that with the solution by corolla from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043506/jquery-ui-autocomplete-disable-select-close-events

Comment: Use: 
`if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
          $scope.$apply();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2" employeesearchautocomplete ng-model="employeeName" name="employeeName">
```

JS

```
 var myApp = angular.module("employeeSearchModule",[]);

        myApp.controller("employeeSearchController",function($scope,$http){

            $scope.message= "Welcome to angular js..."

        });

        myApp.directive('employeesearchautocomplete', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require : 'ngModel',
                link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                      element.autocomplete({
                          source : function(request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                url : "searchEmployee.html",
                                data : request,
                                success : response,
                                dataType : 'json'
                            });
                        },
                        select : function(event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            if (ui.item.value == '-1') {
                                scope.employeeName ='';
                                scope.$apply();
                            } else {
                                scope.employeeName = ui.item.label;
                                scope.$apply();

                            }
                        },
                        focus : function(event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            scope.employeeName = ui.item.label;
                            scope.$apply();
                        },
                        change : function(event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {
                                scope.employeeName ='';
                                scope.$apply();

                            }
                        }
                      },{
                            minLength : 2
                      });


                }
            }
        });
```

Order of script files import

- All your jquery
- AngularJs library
- your angular script for autocomplete

I hope this will help someone.