# using $http in angular.js factory

Tags: angularjs

In my app I am using angular.js and jquery ui autocomplete.  I had the same problem that is discussed
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959516/problems-with-jquery-autocomplete-angularjs)
The accepted answer there works great for me and is exactly what I needed up until today when I need to replace the static array of values with an $http ajax call.
I tried to pass $http as parameter to the parent function but I get "Unknown provider: autoCompleteProvider <- autoComplete"

My question is, how can I use $http without rewriting or changing too much the current solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a callback reference in your getSource() function of your service:

```
app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', ['$http', function($http) {
   return {
       getSource: function(callback) {
          var url = '...';
          $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
             callback(data);
          }
       }
   }
}]);
```

You could also use [$http.jsonp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#jsonp), if your server returns json. Don't forget the JSON_CALLBACK parameter then.

In you directive you need to add the callback function itself:

```
...
autoCompleteDataService.getSource(function(data) {
   elem.autocomplete({
         source: data
         minLength: 2
   });    
});
```

Comment: did it and now i get "TypeError: this.source is not a function"

Comment: Can you setup an example then, since I don't know how you are using the $hhtp service

Comment: i'm sorry i had a typo, i fixed it and now there is no errors, but also no data returns. i use the $http service exactly like in your answer above.

Comment: yes of course i have replaced the url to my web service url and i can see in firebug that the service is returning data successfully, but
the autocomplete is not working and there is no js error

Comment: asgoth - your answer was correct. the problem was that my data was array of objects: [{city_id:x, city_name:y}], after changing it to:
[{key:x, value:y}] the problem solved, how bizzare!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getSource: function() {
            return function(request, response) {
                $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                    response(data);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

}]);

However, if you want to download the entire data first and allow the autocomplete widget to search the data on the client side, this is an example how you can do it:

```
app.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService, $http) {
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        autoCompleteDataService.getData(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Could not retrieve data.");
                return;
            }

            elem.autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: data,
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    elem.val( ui.item.label );
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    elem.val( ui.item.label );
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $scope) {
return {
    getData: function(callback) {
        if ($scope.data) {
            return callback(null, $scope.data);
        }

        $http.get('URL')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            return callback(null, data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            return callback(true, null);
        });
    }
}
```

}]);