# Cant able to fetch data into ng-template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using codeigniter with angular.js. I have created ng-template, i can fetch data from $http method but unble to fetch in ng-template. I am not getting where am doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
//Angular.js
var app1 = angular.module("HomeApp",['uiSlider','ui.bootstrap']);
app1.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/hallinfo', {
      templateUrl: 'hallinfo.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/hallfeature',{
      templateUrl:'hallfeature.html',
      controller:'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/hallinfo"
    });
});

app1.controller('HomeCtrl', function( $scope,$http,$q,$location,$window,$routeParams,$modal, $log) {
$scope.get_hallfeature=function(id){
     return $http({
        url:  'home/get_hallfeatures/'+id,
        method: "POST"
      }).success(function(addData) {
        $scope.hallfeature={};
        $scope.hallfeature=addData; 
        console.log($scope.hallfeature);
        });
    }
}
```

//in above code i am getting data in $scope.hallfeature (i ve seen in console) but not in ng-template

//hallfeature template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="hallinfo.html">
//from here i am passing parameter(hall_id) to get hall features of particular hall
<div ng-repeat = "hall in hallinfo">
//i have my data here 
<button ng-click="get_hallfeature(hall.hall_info_id)"></button>
//on click it goes to my app.js get_hallfeature function
</div>
</script>

//hallfeature template
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="hallfeature.html">
    <div ng-repeat = "feature in hallfeature" >
    <table border="border:3px dashed blue" class="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"  >
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Dining Capacity : </th>
                                <td >{{feature.dining_capacity}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Kitchben Type :</th>
                              <td>{{feature.kitchen_type}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Receiption Capacity :</th>
                              <td>{{feature.receiption_capacity}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Rooms :</th>
                              <td>{{feature.number_of_rooms}}</td>
                            <tr/>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Total Area :</th>
                              <td>{{feature.total_area}}</td>
                              </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Conference Facility:</th>
                              <td>{{feature.conference_facility}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      </div>
    </script>
```

//where as my hallinfo template is working fine. plese tell me where i am making mistake. 
i have trigered get_hallfeature on click from hallinfo ng-template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using $http in angular.js factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045626/using-http-in-angular-js-factory)

Comment: sir mine is not a case of autocomplete, I want data to be repeated in my ng-repeat

Comment: I have not used factory to get my data.

Comment: I have a simple ajax like call to get data from my db it will be called onclick event. so I am getting my data after call but not able to fetch in my ng-template. please tell me is that my calling and assigning is wrong?