# autocompelete in AngularJS and ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

This reference helps a lot in making  directive "autocomplete" with tag . [Problems with jQuery autocomplete + AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959516/problems-with-jquery-autocomplete-angularjs/15792437?noredirect=1#comment22454828_15792437)

However, I have a following problem:

I know in order to handle events after a selection in autocomplete list, should use event handler provided by jqueryUI.

```
...
     link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                elem.autocomplete({
                        source: datasource,
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                             console.log(ui.item.value); 
                             console.log(attrs.ngModel);
                             //but how can I change the value of this ngModel in scope?
                        }

                    });
     };
```

However, in directive, how can I affect the value of that ngModel? I can get the name of that ngModel by using attrs.ngModel.(knowing that **ng-model's name is dynamic** and I can get the value by using ui.item.value)

Does anyone got some idea? Great thanks in advance!

Comment: The value of what exactly?

Comment: Hi Justen thanks for your response. In fact, I can get the name of ngModel, but want to change that ngMoel's value in directive.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you already have the scope defined in your directive but here's a example:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // monitor plugin and set value to ngModel
      element.plugin({
        onChange: function(newValue) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.ngModel = newValue;
          });
        }
      });

      // monitor ngModel and set new value to element/plugin
      scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        element.val(newValue);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much mec! It's exactly the scope.$apply what I want

Answer (score 0):

OK, after playing with this example for a few hours (I'm just learning angular)
I figured that to set the value you need following:

```
ngModel.$setViewValue(elm.val());
```

In particular your code should look like this:

```
require: 'ngModel',
 link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            elem.autocomplete({
                    source: datasource,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                         console.log(ui.item.value); 
                         console.log(attrs.ngModel);

                         ctrl.$setViewValue(elem.val());

                         //but how can I change the value of this ngModel in scope?
                    }

                });
 };
```

So I tested this it works.