# Angularjs jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to implement jquery's autocomplete in an Angular directive. The data I'm receiving for source is coming from websocket response. It's not working and I think response delay is causing the issue here.

I'll appreciate if someone could shed some light on code below. Is there any elegant technique to achieve this using some kind of request/response or promise?

```
app.directive('autoComplete', function($rootScope, locationAutoCompleteService, $timeout, $http, programLocationModel ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        scope: {

            serviceType: '@serviceType'
        },

        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

            var autoItem = [];

            scope.change = function () {

                locationAutoCompleteService.unSubscribe();

                var service = locationAutoCompleteService.getServiceDefinition();

                service.filters.pattern = scope.inputVal;

                locationAutoCompleteService.subscribe();

            };

            scope.$on('myData', function(event, message){

                if ( message !== null && message.results !== null) {

                    autoItem = [];

                    for ( var i = 0; i < message.results.length; i++) {

                        autoItem.push({ label: message.results[i].name, id: message.results[i].id });
                    }

                }

            });

            elem.autocomplete({

                source: autoItem,
                select: function( event, ui ) {

                    $timeout(function() {

                        elem.trigger('input');

                    }, 0);

                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61999853/7772054) will help you, written in jquery+angularjs.

Answer (score 14):

You could always leverage the work these guys have done: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

-Scroll down to typeahead-

Here is a Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9zsrvLLfH8hKGwmIeZVv?p=preview

Here is some markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <pre>Model: {{selected| json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
}
```

**Update**

It seems like I was focussing on the wrong problem. Try moving the autocomplete call inside the `$on` handler.

Like this:

```
app.directive('autoComplete', function($rootScope, locationAutoCompleteService, $timeout, $http, programLocationModel) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            serviceType: '@serviceType'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var autoItem = [];
            scope.change = function() {
                locationAutoCompleteService.unSubscribe();
                var service = locationAutoCompleteService.getServiceDefinition();
                service.filters.pattern = scope.inputVal;
                locationAutoCompleteService.subscribe();
            };
            scope.$on('myData', function(event, message) {
                if (message !== null && message.results !== null) {
                    autoItem = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < message.results.length; i++) {
                        autoItem.push({
                            label: message.results[i].name,
                            id: message.results[i].id
                        });
                    }
                    elem.autocomplete({
                        source: autoItem,
                        select: function(event, ui) {
                            $timeout(function() {
                                elem.trigger('input');
                            }, 0);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but example you have given is working with static data. The code I pasted works great with static array. I'm having trouble updating array from web socket response.

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Can you show your service code? I think your problem might be that your app is not aware of the changes from your websocket and is not triggering the watch

Comment: also, where is myData defined?