# jquery autocomplete doesn't recognize angulars $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I don't know why , but when I try to set the $scope variables Inside the autocomplete , nothing happens , well the $scope variables got undefined,($scope.shipperdescripcion and $scope.shipperlocation) but I need to know how to make it work , thx

```
$(".shipper").autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      source: "controllers/search.php?catalogo=plantas",      
      select: function(event, ui, $scope){       
         $(this).val(ui.item.value).change();
         $scope.shipperdescripcion = ui.item.id;
         $scope.shipperlocation = ui.item.desc;
         return false;
      },
      change: function (event, ui, $scope) {
         if (ui.item == null) {
            $scope.shipperdescripcion = '';
            $scope.shipperlocation = '';
         }
      }
   })
   .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
      .data( "item.autocomplete", item)      
      .append( "<a><b>" + item.value + "</b><br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )      
      .appendTo( ul );
   };
```

Comment: Look into building a directive for this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959516/problems-with-jquery-autocomplete-angularjs

Comment: I'm using this directive now with angular but I don't know how use the  _renderItem , I download it , it's called autocomplete.js

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply()`.