# Angular - Pass value from directive to global scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My app has two fields: Client and Service (engagement). I add autocomplete (using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/19547431/223934) for client. I want to go further step: if I select a client, it will send a request for available services (engagements) for that client and show up in the views as options.

```
CSM.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.availableEngagements = '';
....
```

and directive

```
CSM.directive("autocomplete", ["AutoCompleteService", function (AutoCompleteService) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        action: '@',
        availableEngagements: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, iAttrs, ctrl, http) {
        iAttrs.$observe('action', function (actionValue) {
            elem.autocomplete({
                source: function (searchTerm, response, scope) {
                    AutoCompleteService.search(searchTerm.term, actionValue).then(function (autocompleteResults) {
                        response($.map(autocompleteResults, function (autocompleteResult) {
                            return {
                                label: autocompleteResult.name,
                                value: autocompleteResult.id,
                                desc: autocompleteResult.name
                            };
                        }));
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, selectedItem) {
                    // Do something with the selected item, e.g.
                    scope.selectedValue = selectedItem.item.value;

                    scope.$apply();
                    if (actionValue === "client") {
                        scope.availableEngagements = AutoCompleteService.engagementSearch(selectedItem.item.value);
                        //scope.$apply();
                    }

                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);

CSM.factory("AutoCompleteService", ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        search: function (term, action) {
            return $http.post("autocomplete/" + action + "/", {term: term}).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        },
        engagementSearch: function (client) {
            //Tai sao POST ko duoc ma GET lai duoc?
            $http.get("autocomplete/engagement/?term=" + client).success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I have tried to apply the binding method "=" as in [this guide](https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/). The autocomplete worked fine, the app successfully sent request  and receive results for services (engagements). It just does not pass to global scope to show in the view.

Please help me to point out what's wrong with my code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note is that your directive creates an isolate scope which is a child scope (not prototypically inherited) of it's parent scope. So use `$parent` in the directive to update the scoped object defined on the controller:

```
scope.$parent.availableEngagements = AutoCompleteService.engagementSearch(selectedItem.item.value);
```