# AngularJs ng-model does not work with jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/7y25ru40/

I am implementing the [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) function. It seems that `ng-model` does not work with `autocomplete`.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="origin" ng-model="searchForm.origin" placeholder="City, State">
```

AngularJS:

```
var origin = ["DALLAS, TX", "DALLAS, NE"];

$("#origin").autocomplete({
     source: origin,
     autoFocus: true,
     delay: 0,
     minLength: 3
 });
```

When I type `DAL` in the input and select `DALLAS, TX` from the dropdown list, I actually get `DAL` for `ng-model`. Anyone has a solution? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why not use an angular-specific dropdown?

Comment: @DanielHigueras This is for typeahead feature. Because I am doing company project, so I cannot use Angular Bootstrap, that's why I use jQuery `autocomplete`.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959516/problems-with-jquery-autocomplete-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to create a directive for this.

```
app.directive("autoComplete", function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var location = ["OMAHA, NE", "OMAHA, TX", "DALLAS, TX", "DALLAS, NE"];

                element.autocomplete({
                    source: location,
                    autoFocus: true,
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 3,
                    select: function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            element.trigger("input");
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```