# How to prevent closing the menu after a select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, widget

I am using the [jQuery Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) widget and, inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043506/jquery-ui-autocomplete-disable-select-close-events) in order to *prevent closing the menu after select*, I came up with this code:

```
$(#input_field).autocomplete({
  select   : function(event, ui) {

    // I also tried to run 'ui.item.data( "item.autocomplete" );' and it happens
    // the same thing (keep reading for more information).
    ui.item.option.selected = false;

  },
  ...
});
```

It works: the menu is not closed after select. However, I get the following error (in the Firebug console):

```
TypeError: ui.item.option is undefined
```

Even by using `option.selected = false` I get `TypeError: option is undefined` but it works as expected.

How can I solve that?

Comment: can you provide a testcase on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(ui)` inside the `select` callback function and check your console to see what exactly is being passed in the `ui` parameter.

Comment: @Bogdan - Logging the `ui` object, it is displayed `{ label="The label", value="The value" }`. It is just that that should be.

Comment: Are you using the latest jQuery version? According to the [Autocomplete Widget API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) the `select` event should be passing `ui.item` to the event handler function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no option/method in current jQuery UI to handle this issue.
The method you trying to use is for older versions of jQuery UI. In current version `ui.item` doesn't have proporties you trying to access. It only has `{"label":"Java","value":"java"}` inside, so that's why you have an error.

So to make it works you'll need some sort of hack. By inspecting jQuery UI source code I found that the easiest and most reliable way to do this is to override public `close` method with out custom method. It's really easy to do if you never need to close autocomplete:

```
$("#input_field").data('autocomplete').close = function() {};
```

But it's more complicated if you want to prevent closing only when item is selected with mouse:

```
// custom close method
(function(){
    var instance = $("#input_field").data('autocomplete');
    var origClose = instance.close, mouseFlag;

    // capture mouse events
    instance.menu.element.on('mousedown', function() {
        mouseFlag = true;
    });
    instance.close = function(e) {
        if(!mouseFlag) {
            // call original method if drop isn't closed by mouse
            origClose.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            // clean flag in setTimeout to avoid async events
            setTimeout(function(){
                mouseFlag = false;    
            },1);
        }
    }
}());​
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hcVE/)

Comment: Is there a way to *re-open* the jQuery Autocomplete menu after a `select` event so to avoid hacking?

Comment: I opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550637/how-to-re-open-a-menu-after-a-search) for that.

Comment: No, there's no public method for doing this. It is opened by private `_suggest` method. You should write your custom autocomplete widget, or use some hacks like above I provided.

Comment: You're asking about different things. This question was about how to **prevent** drop from hide, and new is about **open** menu. What about this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/m2jTZ/ ? Don't know how it'll behave on multiple instances of UI Datepicker.

Comment: Why are you introducing Datepicker (and related problems)? Is the Autocomplete related to that widget?

Comment: Thank you for the last jsfiddle solution.