# How to re-open a menu after a select event that involves a search event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, widget

I am using the [jQuery Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) widget and, after a "unsatisfactory" (at least for me) [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542923/how-to-prevent-closing-the-menu-after-a-select) that involved hacking the plugin in order to prevent closing the menu, I am looking for a "less invasive" way to make things with a different approach. So, I would like to know if there is a way to *re-open* the menu after a `select` event that involves a `search` event. That is, given

```
$(#input_field).autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true,
  select   : function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).autocomplete('search', "Custom search string" );
  },
  ...
});
```

*I would like to make the menu to open* (*note*: there is a method to [close](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-close) the menu but not to open it) *after that the user select a item from that menu*. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to do this . use a timer to listen autocomplete close event :

```
var stop = false;
setInterval(function(){
    if(!$('.ui-autocomplete').is(':visible') && !stop)
    {
        $('.ui-autocomplete').css('display','block');
    }
},10);
```

but this is not good way to prevent closing menu !!!!
you can set 'stop' to true when an event happen .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think it is a poor one. There must be a better solution...