# JQUERY Autocomplete (disable click selection)

Tags: javascript, jquery

HiAll,

I use a simply JQUERY Autocomplete to show possibles duplicates for certains records, like Name or address when user fill in a textfield.

Here code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    var availableTags = <?php include('ajax/ajax_show.php'); ?>;
                    $("#name_value").autocomplete({
                        source: availableTags,
                        autoFocus:true
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Below text filed are displayes results.

```
Name[____________________]
 Paul a
 Robert b
 Cid c
```

There is a way to disable selection?
I'm like to use autocomplete only to show records, but user cannot click to select anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Autocomplete disable Select & Close events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043506/jquery-ui-autocomplete-disable-select-close-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to confuse the user with this arrangement, since every other time he starts typing into a box and a list appears, the list will be a list of available options to select.  You're changing the rules, and that doesn't make for the best UX.  I would consider rethinking this.

That said, you can do what you want in the `select` option by calling `preventDefault()` in it:

```
$("#name_value").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus:true,
    select: function(e, ui) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes maybe user going confuse you are right.
Autocomplete show result like this: **Paul James - 123.123.123-12** but in text input when click I need to send only name, in this case **Paul James**. There is a way to make this?

Comment: You could use `substr` to remove the ` - ` (space hyphen space) and everything after it, assuming there isn't any such string in any name.  A more robust option would be to change your `source` to an array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ] and put only the name in the value property.  If you have trouble with this, then post it to a new question.

Comment: Posted :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620427/autocomplete-jquery-remove-everything-after