# Autocomplete Jquery remove everything after ' - '

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a simply JQUERY Autocomplete to show possibles duplicates for certains records, like Name or address when user fill in a textfield.

Here code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    var availableTags = <?php include('ajax/ajax_show.php'); ?>;
                    $("#name_value").autocomplete({
                        source: availableTags,
                        autoFocus:true
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Below text filed are displayes results.

```
Name[____________________]
 Paul - 121.456.789-00
 Robert - 122.456.789-00
 Cid - 123.456.789-00
```

How to remove all after `-` (space hyphen space) and everything after it and have in textfield only name like Paul, Robert or Cid?

Comment: You can't change ajax_show.php? Do you need to use the "121.456.789-00" for something, or can you toss it out completely?

Comment: I need numbers for references, I can have two person with same name but with different record number. Record number is Unique. But if I need to add new person, i need only name, because record number is different.

Comment: @dgig 's answer is the "more robust" solution that I mentioned in my post to your other question, more robust because it doesn't depend on you putting a " - " in the label.  I've posted the `substr`-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply remove the numbers and show the name in an input box, you can use `substr` and `indexOf` (or you can work with regular expressions and `replace` if you prefer).  Like this:

```
$( "#name_value" ).autocomplete({
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#myInputBox').text(ui.item.value.substr(0, ui.item.value.indexOf(" - ")));
    }
});
```

You might want to look up these two functions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to see how this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the `ajax/ajax_show.php` to give you the data the way you want, one of doing that is by using RegEx and replace everything after the `-` with javascript.

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = <?php include('ajax/ajax_show.php'); ?>;
  $("#name_value").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags.map(function(v) { return v.replace(/(^[^-]*) .*/, '$1') }),
    autoFocus:true
   });
 });
```

Basically, this solution is using the `map` function to iterate over all elements and create a **new** `array` with the elements "cleaned" up.
The method `replace` will use a regular expression `(^[^-]*) .*` to grab everything that's before the dash.

You can play with the regular expression if you want something more specific, another example that would work is: `/^(.*) - .*$/`

Comment: But if he needs to keep the numbers then, this just strips them and throws them out, right?

Comment: It won't get rid of the original array. I'm not really sure where nor how the numbers are being used as it's not specified in the question, so I can't help much on that issue.

Comment: Unserstand your approach, but in fact, i need to remove ' - 123.456.789-12' from text input box, after clicking on name.

Suggestion from autocomplete > Cris - 123.123.123-11 > User select suggestion > after click on input box appear only Cris

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I think you'd be better off returning your data from ajax_show.php as json, like:

```
[
  {
   "value": "121.456.789-00",
   "label": "Paul"
  },
  {
   "value": "122.456.789-00",
   "label": "Robert"
  },
  ... 
]
```

Then, as shown in the jQuery UI docs here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data (under the 'Custom Data and display' tab), it will only use the name as the label but you'll still have access to the Id (the value property).

And as added good news, the way you pass your data in (by assigning it to the 'source' property) doesn't need to change at all.